# Trimming the results of a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a email column in my users table that when the function on the user interface is selected to delete the user, it just updates the email address and adds the time to it.

Basically `me@me.com` turns to `me@me.com.1234567`

Now i can search the updated users using :

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '.', 2)
FROM users
```

but the problem I'm having is on the emails that show 2 or 3 decimals before the @ symbol obviously don't show up correctly. So `user.lastname@me.com.1234567` shows as `user.lastname@me` and so forth.

How would i make sure that I am only removing the very last portion behind the very last ' . ' in the result?

Comment: I don't want to post it as an answer because I'm only 95% sure, but the 3 last characters of a domain name ('.com', '.com.ar' etc.) MUST be alphabetic (/[a-z]{2,3}/i) so you could detect the transition between these characters and the *ending* ($) part of the string that is always numeric in your case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

and MUCH More safer way,

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING CONCAT('.',REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(email), '.', 1))) FROM email) email
FROM   Users
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b02c/22

Comment: displays mixed results. about 50% are correct, but the other 50% of results are pulling data that does not have .1234567 at the end

Comment: strange, your fiddle works perfectly, but my database is being retarded.